# Displaying nodes and forms in a block for processing

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I am trying to build a module that enables users to use Drupal as a front end for a BMP engine. Users will be able to use Drupal content in their Processes. For example filling out forms or approving nodes for publication. Filling out a form or approving something will be the completion of a step.

My idea is to display the Drupal content (node, form) in a block and display the step description above it and a button underneath it stating: "Complete Step".

The BMP engine tells Drupal what to display in the block through a node_id or a form_id. Adding a button to a form seems quite easy (even though a way that will always removing/replace the button that calles hook_form_submit is welcome). The Problem is displaying this same button under a node.

After trying a lot of things I am down to this (and it does not work yet but it should not be that big a problem...)

```
//get the node object
$node_object = node_load ($step['DrupalID']);

//get our node submision form  
$form = drupal_get_form('pm_form_form');

$output = drupal_render($form);
$output .= drupal_render(node_view ($node_object, true));
```

Yet it feels like a hack... can anyone suggest a better idea?

Comment: Have you poked around in http://drupal.org/project/formblock/ for ideas?

Comment: Nope I didn't do that yet. Good Idea though. Thx!

Comment: @DavidMeister If you can provide more details, that would be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form Block module lets you easily create "block versions" of your add node forms. These block versions are still forms like any other in Drupal so you can use hook_form_alter to change the Submit button text to whatever you like and/or add any submit/validation handlers as required.

Comment: Thank you, yet my boss seems allergic to depending on modules:( So I am afraid it isn't the solution I am looking for. However, your tip to poke around there is probably what will lead me to the answer.

Comment: Lol, all of my clients are allergic to wasting money. I wonder what would happen if you put them in a room together with your boss?

Comment: ;-) I guess my boss uses cheap labor;-)